# Create NSFetchedResultsController managing entities with many to many relationship

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an entity called `Project` and another entity called `Employee`. Employees work on multiple projects.

`Project` entity has `project name`.

`Employee` entity has `First name`, `last name`, `departmentid number`.

I want the data to show up in section header table like this

> Project 1
>   Dept1
>   -firstname1, lastname1
>   -firstname2,lastname2
>   dept 2
>   firstname3, lastname3
>   firstname4,lastname4
>   Project 2
>   Dept1
>   -firstname1,lastname1

How can I do this? I don't have to display department names, but it has to be sorted that way.

I am using Core Data & `UITableView`. I need to construct `NSFetchResultsController` for this.

Comment: Was the section header examples supposed to be formatted as an outline or did you intend it to be all one line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your question comes from the fact that a to-many relationship results in an NSSet when you access it from the *from* object of the relationship (ie: Project->Employees - results in an NSSet of employees).  NSSets are, of course, unordered.

And the answer is this:

You'll need to sort your employee NSSets by hand.  I suggest you convert the NSSet to an NSMutableArray, and then use -sortUsingBlock: or something along those lines to do it.  To keep yourself from having to re-sort it every time you need it, store it as a member variable of your Project class.  In doing so, it should be pretty easy to create it lazily, and only re-sort it when the dataset changes, which will be better for performance.

You MIGHT be able to do something with a subquery in Core Data... but I think you might find that'll hit the disk more often than you might like. (Just a guess there) The technique I've suggested above is a bit less magical, a bit more brute force, but it'll work, and you'll know exactly how it behaves forever.

Answer (score 0):

Use fetchedResultsController to get your 'Project' entities and you will be able to access and display the `Employee` NSSet in your tableview datasource methods via their relationships.